# Joomla 2.5 installation process silently failing

Tags: joomla-2.5, installation

While attempting to install Joomla 2.5 on a php 5.2 server the install wizard keeps silently failing at the sql settings page.

Is there any way to simply write a config to the server manually?

Comment: sure, just open the joomla package and copy the configuration.php to the server via ftp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me like the script times out while creating the database tables?
The server error log file would likely tell you the reason for it.

To manually install Joomla

1. You need to create the `configuration.php` file. There is an *example* file `installation/configuration.php-dist`. You can take that, adjust it and place it in the root folder as `configuration.php`.
2. You also need to create the database tables. For that you take the SQL file `installation/sql/mysql/joomla.sql`. You need to change the table prefix in the SQL file from `#__` to the one you specify in the configuration. After that you can apply it to the database using phpMyAdmin or similar.